# Is a transit visa required in Stockholm for a resident permit holder of Norway?

Tags: visas, transit, india, oslo, sas

I am travelling from India to Oslo, Norway on a resident permit. I have a transit at Stockholm, Sweden. Do I need a transit visa for the same travel?

Comment: If your resident permit has no restrictions, you should be allowed short visits (up to 90 days) to other Schengen countries. That includes transits on your way for your first visit to your residence country. But do check the permit for details.

Comment: No, no problems. Your Norwegian residence permit allows you to travel the Schengen zone, which both Norway and Sweden are part of.

Comment: To help give a correct answer, please state your nationality (in the question text or by a xxx-citizens tag). By your origin country and name I could assume you're an Indian citizen, but can't be sure.